# ImageView Does Not android:layout_alignRight As Expected

Tags: xml, thumbnails, android, android-xml

I have an imageView which I'd like to have as close as possible to the right side of the screen - however - in it's current implementation it does not seem to be snug against the right border.

I've tried setting:

```
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
```

...but none of those paramaters seem to achive what I'm looking for.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/buyButton"
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:src="@drawable/buy_a_up_btn" />
```

### XML:

```
   <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/uploaderTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:paddingLeft="5dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/verylightgrey"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewCountTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:paddingLeft="6dip"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buyButton"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/buy_a_up_btn" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/videoInfo"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/verylightgrey"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="8dip"
            android:paddingLeft="8dip"
            android:paddingRight="8dip"
            android:paddingTop="13dip" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Post Comment" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:text="SEND"
                android:textColor="@color/verylightgrey" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/name"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/lightgrey"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/published"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/verylightgrey"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

### SCREENSHOT:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/B3feT.png

### Edit

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/uploaderTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="5dip"
            android:textColor="@color/verylightgrey"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewCountTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/uploaderTv"
            android:layout_toRightOf="@id/userVideouploaderTextView"
            android:textColor="@android:color/black"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buyButton"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:src="@drawable/buy_a_up_btn" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/videoInfo"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/verylightgrey"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="8dip"
            android:paddingLeft="8dip"
            android:paddingRight="8dip"
            android:paddingTop="13dip" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Post Comment" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:text="SEND"
                android:textColor="@color/verylightgrey" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/name"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/lightgrey"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/published"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/verylightgrey"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

### Edit

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context=".MainActivity" >

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:id="@+id/youtubeplayerview"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/titleTv"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:paddingLeft="5dp"
        android:text=""
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <RelativeLayout
        android:id="@+id/videoInfo"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:background="@color/white"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/linearLayout"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/uploaderTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/verylightgrey"
            android:textSize="16sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/viewCountTv"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingBottom="5dip"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/uploaderTv"
            android:text=""
            android:textSize="14sp" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/buyButton"
            android:layout_width="50dp"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:src="@drawable/buy_a_up_btn" />
    </RelativeLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_below="@id/videoInfo"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
        android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"

        android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:background="@color/verylightgrey"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:paddingBottom="8dip"
            android:paddingLeft="8dip"
            android:paddingRight="8dip"
            android:paddingTop="13dip" >

            <EditText
                android:id="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="40dp"
                android:layout_weight="1"
                android:background="@color/white"
                android:ems="10"
                android:hint="Post Comment" >

                <requestFocus />
            </EditText>

            <Button
                android:id="@+id/button1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/editText1"
                android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
                android:background="@color/black"
                android:text="SEND"
                android:textColor="@color/verylightgrey" />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/name"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/grey"
            android:textSize="20sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/content"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/name"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="4dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/lightgrey"
            android:textSize="18sp" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/published"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/content"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:gravity="left"
            android:paddingBottom="10dp"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:paddingRight="10dp"
            android:paddingTop="10dp"
            android:text=""
            android:textColor="@color/verylightgrey"
            android:textSize="16sp" />
    </LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: why you use this android:layout_weight="1"

Comment: I removed it and updated the screenshot - it still isn't acting as expected: http://i.stack.imgur.com/B3feT.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `TextView`s in the same `LinearLayout` are `wrap_content` wide. They can take up all the space in the parent `LinearLayout`.

(Also `android:layout_alignParentRight` is a `RelativeLayout` attribute and has no effect in a `LinearLayout` parent.)

One way to fix it is to make the `videoInfo` `LinearLayout` a `RelativeLayout` and make the child positions relative to each other. E.g. make the button align to the right and add a constraint that the text view must be left to the button.

Comment: Thanks! I was able to get it implemented - but my two textviews are overlapping even though I used android:layout_alignRight="@+id/uploaderTv" http://pastebin.com/xqNYm958 any idea what I might have done wrong?

Comment: @user3113035: Constrain the right edge layout of the middle textview to the left of the button.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean... isn't that what I'm trying to do with: android:layout_alignRight="@+id/uploaderTv" (I really appreciate your help BTW!)

Comment: Try e.g. adding `layout_alignLeft:@id/viewCountTv` to the button so the textview's and button's layouts are constrained in relation to each other.

Comment: adding android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/viewCountTv" to uploaderTv results in a force close error

Comment: I added align right (source shown above) the uploaderTv and viewCountTv still overlap

Comment: I'm having a few other issues with this build as well... mind taking a look? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20913058/android-xml-layout-parameters-do-not-function-as-expected

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20911739/adding-a-textview-to-drag-and-drop-interface-android-java